# Shadow control with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I'm using the `v-app-bar` label for my header and I want the shadow of the element to be lighter since it looks too prominent. I'm unable to apply `box-shadow` attribute to the `v-app-bar` element.
should I do?

Comment: app-bar has `elevation` and `flat` props which you can use. `flat` removes the shadow entirely and `elevation` accepts an integer which controls the level of shadow which you can learn more about from [this page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/elevation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1

You can use component prop called `elevation`. Look into the app bar docs into API section (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#api) and select **PROPS** tab you can see elevation prop.

### Method 2

You can use builtin elevation classes. You can read more about them here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/elevation/

### Method 3

Vuetify allows you to customize sass styles.
If you go here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#api and select **SASS** tab you can see that they provide some variables which you can edit.

One of them is `elevation` which is responsible for box-shadow.

Of course to do so you need to have vuetify installed as a vue-cli plugin or in a we pack environment as you can read here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/

### Method 4

You can apply css directly but not to the `v-app-bar` because it's only vuetify component name which then gets generated into HTML. You can inspect your page using e.g. chrome dev tools and see what structure app bar has and then apply css styles to the right element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I've been sorrunding sass-variables a lot but I still can't figure how do they work. I'm trying to modify $app-bar-elevation: 2 !default on my variables.sass files but nothing changes.

Comment: I've edited my answer, because there is more than one way to do it.

Comment: @FelipeGalaz !default modifier in sass variables tells the sass processor that this is the default value, which can be overriden. You need to remove that to override default vuetify styles.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for insistence. 
Elevation does not works for me because the shadow color (too dark at any class).
When trying to modify sass variables like this: 
$headings: (
   'h1': (
     font-family: 'serif'
   ),
 )
I'm getting a  syntax error.
Method 4 shows me a header label but nothing happen if I apply atributes to .header

Comment: So update you question with code you currently have, I cannot help you without seeing any code.

Comment: And if you want to completely change the shadow use Method 4 of my answer.